# Can I destroy all the blocks on a superflat?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm looking for a command compatible with my iOS MCPE Superflat, one which will destroy all dirt, bedrock, and grass blocks.

I've tried `/setblock (~x ~y ~z) air 0 replace <block>`, but it doesn't work.

If anybody knows a command that is able to do what I'm looking for, or knows a map for skyblock, please let me know.

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi watercup, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried /setblock (~x ~y ~z) air 0 replace <block>

Answer (score 3):

There is a superflat void preset for Java edition, but I assume that it doesn't exist for PE.

You cannot place or remove blocks in unloaded chunks, either, so it is impossible to destroy the *entire world*.

Comment: Aw, alright. Thanks for answering though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `/fill ~45 ~-1 ~45 ~-45 ~-4 ~-45 air` (Don't go any higher than ~45 because the max amount of filled blocks is 32767). Or set 3 repeating command blocks, with these commands in them: `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ fill ~45 ~-1 ~45 ~-45 ~-4 ~-45 air 0 replace grass`, `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ fill ~45 ~-1 ~45 ~-45 ~-4 ~-45 air 0 replace dirt`, and `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ fill ~45 ~-1 ~45 ~-45 ~-4 ~-45 air 0 replace bedrock`. this will cover more area and all you have to do is walk (or fly) around.

Comment: For the second option, you can get some friends to help you walk around and remove blocks as well.d

Answer (score -1):

you can use `/fill ~x ~Y ~z ~x ~Y ~z air`

Comment: That doesn't add anything to the existing answers, though.